# Ruby - Calling methods in class definition

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

I was recently sifting through some code and came across something like this:

```
class A

  @@container = {}
  def self.register(a, b)
    @@container[a] = b
  end

  def self.get(a)
    @@contaienr[a]
  end
end


class BRunner < A
  A.register(D, self)

  def self.run
    #...
  end
end

class CRunner < A
  A.register(E, self)

  def self.run
    #...
  end
end


class C
  def self.call
    [D, E].each do |item|
      A.get(item).run()
    end
  end
end
```

`BRunner` and `CRunner` call `register` when their respective class definition blocks are executed at runtime. Then, when class `C` is ran explicitly, it calls what `D` and `E` are mapped to, and call the `run` function This doesn't seem right because to me, this is not clear code. Is this a Ruby thing or just bad programming?

Comment: I think you will find that readers may object to your question because it calls for an opinion, a reason to close the question for being [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Before this gets closed -- yes this is quite common (maybe not quite in this form though), which is quite apparent when using Ruby on Rails. All validations/scope definitions work this way.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You can assume D and E are defined, but their definition isnt relevant to the question. This fake code is just to demonstrate my question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland This is a design pattern best practices question. I removed the part where I explicitly asked for an opinion.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I agree, but is this considered a "good" design practice? It seems like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: Side note the runners inheriting from `A` serves no actual purpose in this question as all the method calls to `A` use an explicit receiver of `A`. Seems that maybe there could be a `Runner` super class if needed to define a default `run` method otherwise the runners can be completely independent all together

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking whether calling methods in a class definition is common in Ruby? The answer is "Yes", it is quite common, for example people often call `Module#attr_reader`, `Module#attr_writer`, `Module#attr_accessor`, `Module#public`, `Module#private`, `Module#protected`, and `Module#include` from within a class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your example, while it is Ruby code, doesn't appear to be a Ruby specific design pattern. I suspect it's a software design pattern someone created for that codebase.

Without context of the actual codebase it's difficult to say whether it's too abstract or "bad", but it's likely there is room for improvement even within the small example you provided.

You can find examples of common software design patterns written in Ruby for comparison:

- https://bogdanvlviv.com/posts/ruby/patterns/design-patterns-in-ruby.html
- https://github.com/davidgf/design-patterns-in-ruby

Comment: You are correct, although I cant identify this pattern among the resources you provided. What do you think the code above is closest to?

Comment: I don't believe it squarely fits into any one of those patterns (which are probably all from the Gang of Four book), or any other named pattern I've seen before (although I have seen Ruby code written as above). Maybe a combination of parts of Template & Observer patterns?